# Где ставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

*Может лучше подать заявку на курсы русского языка?*

Answer (score 1):

***Может*** (пропущено *"быть") вводное слово.* После него нужна запятая:

> *Может, лучше подать заявку на курсы русского языка?*